# "Commutation" of parallel transport with covariant derivative and Riemann curvature tensor

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I'd appreciate it a lot of you could please give me a detailed answer to this question. Alternately, you could just cite a reference too. Let $(M,g)$ be a Riemannian manifold, $c$ a curve on it. You could assume that $c$ is a geodesic if you need to, but I think you might not need it. Let $P_{t_1,t_2}$ denote the parallel transport from $P_{t_1,t_2}:T_{c(t_1)}M\to T_{c(t_2)}M$. Let $\nabla$ denote the covariant derivative for $(M,g)$ and let $R$ denote the $(3,1)$ Riemannian curvature tensor. Let $X,Y,Z$ be vector fields along $c$. Then are the following true:

1) Is $P_{t_1,t_2}(\nabla_{c'}Y(t_1))=\nabla_{c'}(P_{t_1,t_2}(Y(t_1))$ ?

2) Is $P_{t_1,t_2}(R(X,Y)Z)(t_1))=R( P_{t_1,t_2}(X(t_1)), P_{t_1,t_2}(Y(t_1))P_{t_1,t_2}(Z(t_1)) ?$

I think yes to 1) would imply yes to 2).

Please give a detailed answer or a reference/resource.Thanks!

Comment: The RHS of your first equation makes no sense. $P_{t_1,t_2}(Y(t_1))$ is a single vector in $T_{c(t_2)}M$, and _not_ a vector field along $c$, so it is meaningless to take the $c'$ covariant derivative of it.

Comment: For 2, the answer is obviously no. You are equivalently asking the following question: if $X, Y, Z$ are vector fields parallel transported along $c$, is $R(X,Y)Z$ a vector field that is parallel transported along $c$? Taking the covariant derivative with respect to $c$ you see that this is only the case if $\nabla_{c'} R = 0$.

Comment: Note that for the second question, there is no need for $X,Y,Z$ to actually be vector fields along $c$. Your question as posed only depends on the pointwise values of $X,Y,Z$, so we can consider the equivalent problem by extending those vectors to vector fields along $c$ by parallel transport.

Comment: Thanks Willie Wong, I think I understand your comment, I'll comment further o, these questions are motivated by some other questions that I have.